# Convert powerpoint to markdown

Tags: shell, conversion, microsoft-powerpoint, file-format, markdown

Can I convert powerpoint to markdown?

My ultimate goal is to create an easily versionable version of the powerpoint. (Maybe reveal.js or something)

Comment: [PowerPoint to Markdown converter](https://github.com/revan/pptx2md#powerpoint-to-markdown-converter)

Comment: Heh, see the discussion we had.

Comment: Huh. What discussion?

Comment: That one on the github :)

Answer (score 2):

[Is it possible to diff PowerPoint version-controlled with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32259943/239408) has, as today, two suggestions to extract text from powerpoint (but no markdown, sorry):

- python-based: [python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- node.js-base: [textract](https://github.com/dbashford/textract)